# I wanted to move the player on x position of the ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a 2D game like asteroids and I wanted the ground to follow the player X position but it give me an error this is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform playerPos;



    private void Update()
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = playerPos.position.x;
    }
}
```

This is the error message: *cannot implicity convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you are trying to assign a `float` (the x position of your `palyerPos`) to the position of your gameObject (which is a `Vector3`).

As you cannot just assign the x value of a `transform.position` I recommend you to buffer your `gameObject` position in a local variable, modify this variable and then reassign the modified position to the `gameObject` transform !

Hope I was clear enough :)